# Magento 2: how to set an element to disappear when viewing in mobile device?

Tags: magento2, rwd, design

In Blank theme, the header account links disappear from header when viewing in mobile device.
Since I moved those links to another area of my store, I want to set the CSS rules to do the same.

I tried the following code in my custom theme which overrides Blank but didn't work:

`@media only screen and (min-width: @screen__m) {
    .header.content .links {
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
.header.content .links {
    display: none;
}`

I want the links display when screen is 768px or wider but disappear otherwise.

Why are those CSS rules duplicated?

[image: Duplicated CSS rules]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you set `display: none` *after* the media query, resulting the media query having no effect.
You need to reorder the rules like this:

```
.header.content .links {
     display: none;
 }
 @media only screen and (min-width: @screen__m) {
    .header.content .links {
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```